# How to delete row when condition met in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements

I want to delete one of duplicate rows when the condition is met.

When "Client" and "year" are the same and "type" is different delete one of the duplicate row (which corresponds to a larger value in cost).

```
client<- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4, 5,5)
year <- c(2000, 2010, 2000, 2003, 2007, 2009, 2009, 2012, 2017, 2017)
type<-c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C","D","D", "A" , "C", "D")
cost<- c(34,56,78, 45,12,56,67,23,10, 89)
data<- tibble(cient,year, type,value)

client year type cost

1 1 2000 A 34
2 1 2010 A 56
3 1 2000 B 78
4 2 2003 B 45
5 2 2007 C 12
6 3 2009 D 56
7 3 2009 D 67
8 4 2012 A 23
9 5 2017 C 10
10 5 2017 D 89
```

As a result row # 3 and row #10 should get deleted and the result should look like this:

```
client year type cost

1 1 2000 A 34
2 1 2010 A 56
3 2 2003 B 45
4 2 2007 C 12
5 3 2009 D 56
6 3 2009 D 67
7 4 2012 A 23
8 5 2017 C 10
```

I am new to tidyverse and couldn't write a command that will filter a row with condition.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

We can use a combination of `row_number` and `slice_min` to do accomplish this. The grouped `row_number` is a sort of counter within a client-year-type grouping.

```
data %>%
    group_by(client, year, type) %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    group_by(client, year, rn) %>%
    slice_min(cost)

  client  year type   cost    rn
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <int>
1      1  2000 A        34     1
2      1  2010 A        56     1
3      2  2003 B        45     1
4      2  2007 C        12     1
5      3  2009 D        56     1
6      3  2009 D        67     2
7      4  2012 A        23     1
8      5  2017 C        10     1
```